# Best way to deploy jekyll based site in sharepoint?

Tags: github, sharepoint-2010, jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-bootstrap

I have created Jekyll site. Which creates html file for each `Markdown` file. It is hosted in sharepoint. What is the best way to update it ?

I don't want each time to generated site locally and copy the html file across to sharepoint.

Suggest some best way to deploy ?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to deploy is to open the SharePoint site in Windows Explorer, which is an option under the Actions menu when you're browsing SharePoint using Internet Explorer.  This will enable you to interact with SharePoint as a regular network filesystem.

Then once you've built your site using Jekyll, you can deploy it by simply copying the output files from `_site` into the appropriate SharePoint folder.

Alternately, you can use the `--destination` flag on Jekyll's `build` command to build straight into the mapped SharePoint directory.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using Windows Operating System. So follow this [guide](https://github.com/juthilo/run-jekyll-on-windows) to run Jekyll on Windows.